# Series Expansion of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, taylor-expansion

This problem is proposed for programming purpose. Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two given polynomials. I'd like to calculate the coefficients of the series expansion of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ under two conditions, respectively. How to obtain the coefficients efficiently?

a) I'm happy with the coefficients having a given number of significant digits;

b) I'm happy with the coefficients modulo a given number, say $M$.

Edit: I notice that the coefficients may satisfy some linear recurrence relationship.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you meant by "efficiently", or what conditions you are allowed to put on $f$ (e.g. for (a) does coefficients live in $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?  For (a) and (b), is it is square-free?)

Comment: I mean calculating the coefficients in reasonable time using a programming language.

Comment: so if $f(x)=a+bx+cx^2$ ... then $g(x)=1/f(x)=$ ... well $g(0)=1/a$ and $g'(0)=-b/a^2$ and $g''(0)=$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh man, there is a really cool answer to this! First I will show how to compute arbitrarily many coefficients of $\frac1{f(x)}$. You can then compute $f(x)/g(x)$ by multiplying $f(x)$ with a large enough Taylor expansion of $1/g(x)$. I got this information from *Modern Computer Algebra 3ed* by Joachim von zur Gathen and Jurgen Gerhard, p. 259.

---

First of all, you need to assume that the constant term of $f$ is $1$. If it is zero, then fix this by factoring out a power of $x$ so what remains has a nonzero constant term, and then factor out whatever that constant term is so what remains has a constant term of $1$. The factored out terms must be factored back in at the end.

From now on, assume $f(0)=1$. Define the following sequence of polynomials, $g_0,g_1,\dots$ recursively by

\begin{align}
g_0 &= 1\\
g_i &= 2g_{i-1}-fg_{i-1}^2\pmod{x^{2^i}} \tag{$i\ge 1$}
\end{align}

You can then show that the first $2^n$ coefficients of $g_n$ will agree with that of the Taylor series of $1/f(x)$. This means that you only need $\log n$ steps to get $n$ digits of $1/f(x)$.

You can ignore the $\pmod{x^{2^i}} $ part if you like, but this offers a speed-up opportunity. It says that during the $i^{th}$ step, you only need to keep track of the first $2^i$ coefficients of $g_i$, so you only need the first $2^{i}$ coefficients of $f$ to compute $g_i$.

Finally, if you use FFT polynomial multiplication to compute $g_i$, this will all in all only take $O(n\log n)$ arithmetic operations to get the first $n$ coefficients of $1/f(x)$.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you very much.